# Deploying a JavaFX Application with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, javafx

Ive gone through tons of documentation and tutorials but nothing seems to work. Heres what i need

- I want to package an deploy a desktop JavaFX application as a self contained package for Mac and Windows.
- I want the application to have a custom icon (of course)
- I want this application to be able to reference a text file that is in a resources folder (that can be modified by the user) to connect to a database.

Here is what i have tried:

- Building artifacts in IntelliJ -This creates a jar with related 3rd party jars and a bundle folder with an exe and dmg. The icon is the default java one, and i cant reference by db.config file from the exe or dmg, i can reference it from the jar however
- Generating an ANT build file - Once created this file contains errors complaining that various tags are not allowed and that properties are not defined.
- Ive tried placing my .ico image which is the same name as my **deployed** application in every possible folder.

Im in serious need of help.

build.xml : http://tinypic.com/r/2md2zbn/8

Comment: If you want to package for both Mac and Windows machines, you need both Mac and Windows machines.  Do you have that?   If you want to package as an exe, [innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) needs to be installed.  Have you done that?  For assistance debugging you ANT build file, you will need to include the build file in your question.

Comment: so i cant build for Windows and Mac platfroms with just a Mac. Im getting Inno Setup now, i didnt know i needed that.

Comment: Are there any alternatives for inno setup  on Mac that you know of?

Comment: Innosetup is only for Windows, OS X comes with it's own packaging tools.  Information on packaging with OS X is included in the [JavaFX deployment guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).